Task :app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
I tried to run the app on my physical device by running npx expo run:android then I got an exception error. This app doesnt have any changes yet I was just gonna check if I can run it on my android device.
› Building app...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-asset (11.0.1)
  - expo-constants (17.0.3)
  - expo-file-system (18.0.4)
  - expo-font (13.0.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (14.0.1)
  - expo-modules-core (2.1.1)

Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-162 Warning:
        application@android:usesCleartextTraffic was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:6 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:0 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

Task :app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1210] C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\cmake-utils\default-app-setup\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 56s
143 actionable tasks: 67 executed, 76 from cache
Error: C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:67:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:630:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:515:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:28:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.ts:134:28)
    at assembleAsync (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.ts:83:16)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\gerar\Desktop\Programming\React_Native\GS-Point-Out-System\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.ts:48:24)

I haven't tried anything yet since when I am trying to find any articles about the error CXX1210 it seems like there are few and aren't answered yet.

You checked this also?

yes, i did from renaming the file, updating ninja.exe to support long file paths, making the newArch=false, updating ndk, installing c/c++ related softwares, updating dependencies, updadating sdk and other solutions from github but I still have the same issue
